# Haskell; from [[String]] to Class & Feature-vector (Double, [Double])

Tags: list, parsing, csv, haskell

I am struggling with reading from a large data set. I think the main issue is that I don't know how to process lists properly. What I want to do is:

1. Get the raw-data.
2. Drop empty lists in the raw-data.
3. Read the features that exist in [[String]]: [####, A/B, #,#,#,#]
4. Have the result in [Double, [Double]]: [ 1/0, #,#,#,#]

EDIT: The below post is somewhat messy, therefore I will attempt to summarize/clarify here. I believe the remainder of the topic can be skipped, but as I am not able to say with certainty what is needed and what is not I leave it there - in case anyone needs it.

So far I have two functions, and the next step is to implement a third that calls on both of them. The goal further down the road is to parse through a dataset, giving me a list of lists of Doubles - with a class label and a feature vector for each instance.

However, for the time being I will  be happy with just calling the function with a "dummy" string. Baby steps.

The functions I have implemented, and that works separately are "numericLabel" and "numericFeatures".

Example of raw data `([String]) = [32142, "B", 1,2,0.4,3,2]`
                     Meaning: (ID#, Class label, features)

```
numericLabel :: [Char] -> Int 
numericLabel x = (if(isBenign x)
                    then 1
                    else if(isMalign x)
                    then -1
                    else 0)



numericFeatures :: [String] -> [Double]
numericFeatures [] = []
numericFeatures (x:xs) = (read x :: Double) : numericFeatures xs
```

These two functions works by calling numericLabel "B or M" and numericFeatures [1,2,0.4,3,2]. The first returns Double, the second returns [Double]. Both read from String.

The function I am having a hard time implementing is one that takes the whole [String], including both the redundant "ID", the char for conversion to Double, and the [String] for conversion to [Double].

Goal: To call on `processItem [32142, "B", 1,2,0.4,3,2]` which then in turns call on the abovementioned functions for the different parts of the Item, `returning: (Double,[Double]) (for this example: (1,[1.0 2.0 0.4 3.0 2.0]) )`

PARSING: As benjic mentions, parsing is probably the solution I would be looking for if I knew what I was doing. But trying to utilize parsing examples was pretty much impossible within the scope of my skillset.

ASMENTIONED: Below here is what I consider to be unneccessary information, I believe all is stated in this "EDIT". But for possible need I leave it there.

```
import Text.CSV

type Label = Double
type Feats = [Double]

getRawData' :: String -> IO [[String]]
getRawData' fn = do
    s <- readFile fn 
    return $ parseCSVsimple s 
-- Return: Wraps given value in an IO action. 

getRawData :: String -> IO [[String]]
getRawData fn = do
    d <- getRawData' fn
    return (dropEmpty d)

dropEmpty :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
dropEmpty d = filter(not . null) d --filter(not.null) d

isBenign :: [Char] -> Bool
isBenign x = x == "M" 
isMalign :: [Char] -> Bool
isMalign x = x == "B" 

isChar :: [Char] -> Bool
isChar = (`elem` ['A'..'Z'])

numericLabel :: [Char] -> Int 
numericLabel x = (if(isBenign x)
                then 1
                else if(isMalign x)
                then -1
                else 0)

numericFeatures :: [String] -> [Double]
numericFeatures [] = []
numericFeatures (x:xs) = (read x :: Double) : numericFeatures xs


This below here is just garbage, and what I need help with. 
--processItem :: [String] -> (Label,Feats)
--processItem st takeWhile (not . isChar)  
--processItem   Label = numericLabel filter (isChar) x:xs 
--processItem   Feats = numericFeatures filter (not . isChar) x:xs
```

Comment: Have you looked into the Parsec library? It allows for the construction of dynamic parsers.

Comment: First of all; I am very sorry for violating the rules. I will try to clarify by editing my original post, and will not do it again. I am new to this forum, but I still know it is my own responsibility to understand the rules. 

Second; I have looked at this, I think, but it overwhelmed me pretty fast. That is why I concluded that my skillset not yet allow me to take advantage of the suggested library.